# Using of \usetikzlibrary in an expl3 package fails

Tags: tikz-pgf, package-writing, documentclass-writing, expl3

In the example below I provided a small test package `mytestpackage.sty` which uses the syntax of `expl3`.

If I use the command `\usetikzlibrary` inside the package I will get the error:
Runaway argument?

```
v\pgfversion ]$Header:/cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mytestpackage.sty}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mytestpackage}{2012/05/26} {0.1}{mytestpackage}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds,arrows,matrix}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{mytestpackage}
\begin{document}
foo bar
\end{document}
```

The first quick fix is:

```
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds,arrows,matrix}
\ExplSyntaxOn
```

How can I patch TikZ (`\usetikzlibrary`) to use it inside my package?

Based on this solution we can send a bug report.

Comment: Using TikZ in an `expl3` context is quite hard, because it relies on the space being a space and probably also on `:` and `_` having their normal category code.

Comment: You could load `tikz` and the tikzlibraries before `\ProvidesExplPackage`

Comment: @egreg: The reason is very simple -- to provide a package or class based on expl3

Comment: @cgnieder: This is the other solution. In the chat Joseph found the problem.

Comment: @cgnieder: Joseph provided the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue arises not because of the catcode of `:` or `_` but because of that of spaces: the code `pgf` uses to find versions from RCS-style data relies on the presence of a space. Perhaps the cleanest fix is to alter the behaviour of the internals of `\usetikzlibary` so that the LaTeX2e push/pop filename system is used. This is already updated by `expl3` to deal correctly with `\ExplSyntax...`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mytestpackage.sty}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mytestpackage}{2012/05/26} {0.1}{mytestpackage}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\patchcmd
  {\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists}
  {\input #1}
  {%
    \@pushfilename
    \xdef\@currname{#1}%
    \input #1 %
    \@popfilename
  }
  {}{}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds,arrows,matrix}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{mytestpackage}
\begin{document}
foo bar
\end{document}
```

You could of course do the same 'directly' by copying the entire definition of `\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists` if you want to avoid using `etoolbox`, but that does not make the solution clearer so I've skipped it. (Note: this patch has been updated for v3 of `pgf`: the older version did much the same thing but targeting a macro no longer used internal by `pgf`.)

---

For `tcolorbox`'s `tcbuselibrary`, patch its `\tcb@input@library@in` in a similar way:

```
\patchcmd
  {\tcb@input@library@in}
  {%
    \input\tcbpkgprefix#1\relax%
  }
  {%
    \@pushfilename
    \input\tcbpkgprefix#1\relax%
    \@popfilename
  }
  {}{}
```

Comment: Regarding the OP, the `calc` TikZ library is enough to points out an issue, which nowadays generates the following error: `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/cs/point/.storein [...] l.410 \tikzset{cs/point/.store in=\tikz@cs@point}'`.
The trouble clearly comes from the space in `.store in` ignored as usually with `expl3` but I believed it was the case only between explicit `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`. Since 2012 (date of the OP), no progress on this subject?