# Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `of'

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I have a single block of tikzpictures, the document compiles.  See code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!50}   

\begin{document} 

\begin{mdframed} [everyline=true, splitbottomskip = 10mm, splittopskip = 10mm, innertopmargin = 10mm, innerbottommargin = 10mm] 

\noindent \textit{\textbf{Example(s) 3.3 and 3.4:}} Consider two games modeled by the following figures. \vspace{3mm}
\begin{center}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning} \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=6, yscale=8,>=stealth] 
\tikzstyle{v}=[circle, minimum size=1mm,draw,thick] \node[v] 
(a) {$a$}; \node[] (x)
 [right=of a]{}; \node[v] (c) [below=of x]{$c$}; \draw[thick,->] (a) to node {}(c);
\node[] (y)
 [left=of a]{};  \node[v] (b) [below=of y]{$b$}; \draw[thick,->] (a) to node {}(b);
\draw[thick,->] (b) to node {}(c);
\node[v] (e) [below=of c]{$e$};
\node[v] (d) [below=of b]{$d$};
 \draw[thick,->] (b) to node {}(d);
 \draw[thick,->] (c) to node {}(e);
 \draw[thick,->] (c) to node {}(d);
\end{tikzpicture} \vspace{3mm}

\textit{Figure 3.5} \vspace{3mm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=6, yscale=8,>=stealth] 
\tikzstyle{v}=[circle, minimum size=1mm,draw,thick] \node[v] 
(a) {$a$}; \node[] (x)
 [right=of a]{}; \node[v] (c) [below=of x]{$c$}; \draw[thick,->] (a) to node {}(c);
\node[] (y)
 [left=of a]{};  \node[v] (b) [below=of y]{$b$}; \draw[thick,->] (a) to node {}(b);
\draw[thick,->] (b) to node {}(c);
\node[v] (e) [below=of c]{$e$};
\node[v] (d) [below=of b]{$d$};
\node[v] (f) [right=of c]{$f$};
\node[v] (i) [left=of d]{$i$};
\node[v] (h) [below=of e]{$h$};
 \draw[thick,->] (d) to node {}(f);
\draw[thick,->] (e) to node {}(h);
\draw[thick,->] (h) to node {}(f);
 \draw[thick,->] (b) to node {}(i);
\draw[thick,->] (i) to node {}(c);
\draw[thick,->] (d) to node {}(h);
 \draw[thick,->] (b) to node {}(d);
 \draw[thick,->] (a) to node {}(e);
 \draw[thick,->] (c) to node {}(d);
 \draw[thick,->] (e) to node {}(d);
 \draw[thick,->] (i) to node {}(d);
\end{tikzpicture} \vspace{3mm}

\textit{Figure 3.6}
\end{center}

\end{mdframed} \vspace{5mm}


\end{document}
```

If I then add text after the block of tikzpictures, then add a new tikzpicture environment, the document does not compile.  See code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!50} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{mdframed} [everyline=true, splitbottomskip = 10mm, splittopskip = 10mm, innertopmargin = 10mm, innerbottommargin = 10mm] 

\noindent \textit{\textbf{Example(s) 3.3 and 3.4:}} Consider two games modeled by the following figures. \vspace{3mm}
\begin{center}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning} \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=6, yscale=8,>=stealth] 
\tikzstyle{v}=[circle, minimum size=1mm,draw,thick] \node[v] 
(a) {$a$}; \node[] (x)
 [right=of a]{}; \node[v] (c) [below=of x]{$c$}; \draw[thick,->] (a) to node {}(c);
\node[] (y)
 [left=of a]{};  \node[v] (b) [below=of y]{$b$}; \draw[thick,->] (a) to node {}(b);
\draw[thick,->] (b) to node {}(c);
\node[v] (e) [below=of c]{$e$};
\node[v] (d) [below=of b]{$d$};
 \draw[thick,->] (b) to node {}(d);
 \draw[thick,->] (c) to node {}(e);
 \draw[thick,->] (c) to node {}(d);
\end{tikzpicture} \vspace{3mm}

\textit{Figure 3.5} \vspace{3mm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=6, yscale=8,>=stealth] 
\tikzstyle{v}=[circle, minimum size=1mm,draw,thick] \node[v] 
(a) {$a$}; \node[] (x)
 [right=of a]{}; \node[v] (c) [below=of x]{$c$}; \draw[thick,->] (a) to node {}(c);
\node[] (y)
 [left=of a]{};  \node[v] (b) [below=of y]{$b$}; \draw[thick,->] (a) to node {}(b);
\draw[thick,->] (b) to node {}(c);
\node[v] (e) [below=of c]{$e$};
\node[v] (d) [below=of b]{$d$};
\node[v] (f) [right=of c]{$f$};
\node[v] (i) [left=of d]{$i$};
\node[v] (h) [below=of e]{$h$};
 \draw[thick,->] (d) to node {}(f);
\draw[thick,->] (e) to node {}(h);
\draw[thick,->] (h) to node {}(f);
 \draw[thick,->] (b) to node {}(i);
\draw[thick,->] (i) to node {}(c);
\draw[thick,->] (d) to node {}(h);
 \draw[thick,->] (b) to node {}(d);
 \draw[thick,->] (a) to node {}(e);
 \draw[thick,->] (c) to node {}(d);
 \draw[thick,->] (e) to node {}(d);
 \draw[thick,->] (i) to node {}(d);
\end{tikzpicture} \vspace{3mm}

\textit{Figure 3.6}
\end{center}

\end{mdframed} \vspace{5mm}

text stuff

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=6, yscale=8,>=stealth] 
\tikzstyle{v}=[circle, minimum size=1mm,draw,thick] \node[v] 
(a) {$a$}; \node[] (x)
 [right=of a]{}; \node[v] (c) [below=of x]{$c$}; \draw[thick,->] (a) to node {}(c);
\node[] (y)
 [left=of a]{};  \node[v] (b) [below=of y]{$b$}; \draw[thick,->] (a) to node {}(b);
\draw[thick,->] (b) to node {}(c);
\node[v] (e) [below=of c]{$e$};
\node[v] (d) [below=of b]{$d$};
\node[v] (f) [right=of c]{$f$};
\node[v] (i) [left=of d]{$i$};
\node[v] (h) [below=of e]{$h$};
 \draw[thick,->] (d) to node {}(f);
\draw[thick,->] (e) to node {}(h);
\draw[thick,->] (h) to node {}(f);
 \draw[thick,->] (b) to node {}(i);
\draw[thick,->] (i) to node {}(c);
\draw[thick,->] (d) to node {}(h);
 \draw[thick,->] (b) to node {}(d);
 \draw[thick,->] (a) to node {}(e);
 \draw[thick,->] (c) to node {}(d);
 \draw[thick,->] (e) to node {}(d);
 \draw[thick,->] (i) to node {}(d);
\end{tikzpicture} \vspace{3mm}


\end{document}
```

I've skimmed the TikZ/PGF Manual, but the answer is not jumping out at me.  Any suggestions regarding what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In case someone bumps into the same issue as me: I was having this error but had `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` loaded, or so I thought. I'm using the `standalone` library and have a `diagram.tex` file where I loaded `positioning`. However, there is a `main.tex` that includes `diagram.tex` in a figure environment and I should have the `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` in `main.tex` because I was trying to compile `main.tex` and not `diagram.tex`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I get the following error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `of' (in 'of a').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.76  [right=of a]
                  {}; \node[v] (c) [below=of x]{$c$}; \draw[thick,->] (a) to...

?
```

The syntax `right=of a` is an extension/feature of library `positioning`. Therefore, the error is fixed by loading the library. Add the following line to the preamble:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
```

Comment: That solved the problem!  Thank you for the help!

Comment: @heiko-oberdiek Is there any other explanation for this happening?  I was using the old `right of=node` notation but it is deprecated and I am switching over to the `right=of node` notation.  I have the `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` at the top of my preamble after loading `\usepackage{tikz}` and I get this same error message for some reason.

Comment: I'll just add that I'm working in Latex3 and had to use the patching method described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57428).  I only have problems with the `positioning` library, not any others.

Comment: I decided to post this as a new question over here: [\usetikzlibrary{positioning} in an expl3 package but PGF Math Error: Unknown function `of'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358530/usetikzlibrarypositioning-in-an-expl3-package-but-pgf-math-error-unknown-fun)