# Using tikz within an expl3 package or class (2017 edition)

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3, package-writing, documentclass-writing

This question follows the question [Using of \usetikzlibrary in an expl3 package fails](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57424/using-of-usetikzlibrary-in-an-expl3-package-fails/). While the linked question worked some time ago, its answers seem not to be working anymore.

The question: How can I use `\usetikzlibrary` within an expl3 package or class without getting an error like

```
v\pgfversion ]$Header:/cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

MWE (copied from the other post's answer):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mytestpackage.sty}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mytestpackage}{2012/05/26} {0.1}{mytestpackage}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\patchcmd
  {\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists}
  {\input #1}
  {%
    \@pushfilename
    \input #1 %
    \@popfilename
  }
  {}{}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{mytestpackage}
\begin{document}
foo bar
\end{document}
```

The error I get (with fully updated TL2017):

```
! I can't find file `t{i}kzlibrarycalc.code.tex'.
<argument> ...filename \input tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
                                                  \@popfilename \relax 
l.20 \usetikzlibrary{calc}
```

Comment: It works if you use `\@pushfilename \relax \input {#1}{#2}\@popfilename`  in the patch, but it looks like an expl3 bug so better wait for @JosephWright.

Comment: Actually in https://www.texdev.net/2015/07/30/making-custom-loaders-expl3-aware/ @JosephWright writes that one should add `\xdef\@currname{#1}` after `\@pushfilename`. With it your example works fine too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you'd add it as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it, as I seemingly didn't find this solution.

Comment: I've fixed the older answer: I'd missed out setting `\@currname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in https://www.texdev.net/2015/07/30/making-custom-loaders-expl3-aware/ one should set `\@currname` after a `\@pushfilename`.

With older expl3 version you didn't get an error but now there is at the end of `\@pushfilename` the command `\@pushfilenameaux` which really expects "two commands and an argument" behind it.

So with this change your file compiles again:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mytestpackage.sty}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mytestpackage}{2012/05/26} {0.1}{mytestpackage}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\patchcmd
  {\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists}
  {\input #1}
  {%
    \@pushfilename
    \xdef\@currname{#1}%
    \input #1 %
    \@popfilename
  }
  {}{}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{mytestpackage}
\begin{document}
foo bar
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mytestpackage.sty}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mytestpackage}{2012/05/26} {0.1}{mytestpackage}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{mytestpackage}
\begin{document}
foo bar
\end{document}
```

[image]