# \AddToHook{file/⟨file-name⟩/before}{\ExplSyntaxOff} seems to be ineffective

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3, package-writing, documentclass-writing

(The current question is related to [Using of \usetikzlibrary in an expl3 package fails](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57424/18401), at least somehow.)

Suppose a (`expl3`) class of mine, `myclass`, provides a way to configure it at the document level by means of a configuration file `myclass.cfg` automatically input at the end of the class:

```
\ProvidesExplClass{myclass}{2022-09-01}{0.1}{A class of mine}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }

\file_if_exist:nT {./myclass.cfg}{
  \file_input:n {./myclass.cfg}
}
```

Suppose now a user wants to take advantage of this configuration file `myclass.cfg` to load the `TikZ` package and its `calc` library. This will fail with the following error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/cs/point/.storein', to wh
ich you passed '\tikz@cs@point ', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you miss
pelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.410 \tikzset{cs/point/.store in=\tikz@cs@point}
                                                 %
?
```

as already explained in the related question and pointed out by the following MCE:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{myclass}{2022-09-01}{0.1}{A class of mine}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }

\file_if_exist:nT {./myclass.cfg}{
  \file_input:n {./myclass.cfg}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myclass.cfg}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
```

The trouble clearly comes from the space in `.store in`, ignored as usually with `expl3`. So, as a workaround, it is enough to add `\ExplSyntaxOff` at the beginning of the configuration file. Indeed, the following MCE compiles like a charm:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{myclass}{2022-09-01}{0.1}{A class of mine}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }

\file_if_exist:nT {./myclass.cfg}{
  \file_input:n {./myclass.cfg}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myclass.cfg}
\ExplSyntaxOff         % ← NEW!
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
```

Suppose I would like to make easier the life of the users of my class and to not require from them to add, if needed, `\ExplSyntaxOff` at the beginning of the configuration file. I hoped I could automatically add this command to this file at the class level, by means of hooks, using `\AddToHook { file/myclass.cfg/before } { \ExplSyntaxOff }`. But the following MCE fails with the same error as above:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{myclass}{2022-09-01}{0.1}{A class of mine}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }

\file_if_exist:nT {./myclass.cfg}{
  \AddToHook { file/myclass.cfg/before } { \ExplSyntaxOff } % ← NEW!
  \file_input:n {./myclass.cfg}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myclass.cfg}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
```

Do you understand why and how I could achieve this? (I know I could instead just do at the end of the class:

```
\ExplSyntaxOff
\IfFileExists{./myclass.cfg}{%
  \input{./myclass.cfg}%
}{}
```

but I would have preferred stay with `expl3`: name of the file in a token list constant, etc.)

Comment: you should use the push/popfilename command.

Comment: Apparently, the hook is not applied with `\file_input:n` but it is with `\input`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you elaborate?

Comment: @egreg Good to know! Is it worth to report to `ltfilehook` maintainers?

Comment: @egreg Well, could you elaborate? If I replace `\file_input:n {./myclass.cfg}` with `\input{./myclass.cfg}` in my last MCE, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Do `\AddToHook { file/myclass.cfg/before } { \ExplSyntaxOff }`

Comment: @egreg Oooops! You're right. I'll fix the MCE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\file_input:n` does not look for hooks, which are intended for use with `\input`.

If you do

```
\file_if_exist:nT {./myclass.cfg}
 {
  \AddToHookNext { file/myclass.cfg/before } { \ExplSyntaxOff }
  \AddToHookNext { file/myclass.cfg/after } { \ExplSyntaxOn }
  \input {./myclass.cfg}
 }
```

then it works, but I'm not convinced you want to use hooks:

```
\file_if_exist:nT {./myclass.cfg}
 {
  \use:n { \ExplSyntaxOff \file_input:n {./myclass.cfg} }
  \ExplSyntaxOn
 }
```

Since `\file_input:n` is in the argument to `\use:n`, it is already tokenized, so `\ExplSyntaxOff` does nothing to it.

Answer (score 3):

As written in the answer to other question you link to, LaTeX has a system to set and reset such catcodes when loading files: You can load tikz and other non-expl3 packages without problems in your expl3-class because `\usepackage` makes use of this. `tcolorbox` makes use of this too, and so there is no problem to load its libraries. You can use that for your files too.

See e.g. https://www.texdev.net/2015/07/30/making-custom-loaders-expl3-aware/

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{myclass}{2022-09-01}{0.1}{A class of mine}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }

\file_if_exist:nT {./myclass.cfg}{
  \@pushfilename
  \xdef\@currname{myclass.cfg}
  \file_input:n {./myclass.cfg}
  \@popfilename
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myclass.cfg}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
Foo.
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK but is something simpler planned? And is it the best way to go or is it as good as egreg's solution ?

Comment: what is complicated? Compared to switching expl-syntax on and off it has the advantage that it works in non-expl-classes too and that hooks in the cfg will get their own label as \@currname has been changed.

Comment: By simpler, I meant a single, provided by `expl3`, command for all this stuff :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé this is not only expl3 specific, that is the command that also switches makeatletter on and off. If you want a single command, don't use a cfg but load a style, then you can use \usepackage.

Comment: I guessed this wasn't `expl3` specific but I expected an `expl3` wrapper for all this stuff. But I must admit I don't fully understand most of these push/popfilename commands. About config file versus style file, the latter does not seem to me to be suitable for the end user of a class (but I could be wrong).